# Why use !== when you can use ===?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operators

I could simply vice versa the code to be executed by the if and else. And === is more easier to use compared to !== so why is the not equal operator used?

```
function equality( number ){
    if ( number === 7 ){
        return "it's equal"
    } else { return "not equal"}
}
 console.log(equality(7))

function nonEquality( number ){
    if ( number !== 7 ){
        return "it's not equal"
    } else { return "it's equal"}
}
console.log(nonEquality(7));
```

Comment: Because sometimes you need to use the "not equals" syntax. Depends on the circumstance.

Comment: In your piece of code, you can replace the !== code with the === code. But what if you want to perform some action, if and only if a condition is not true? It would not make sense to make an "if condition is true - else..." instead of a simple "if condition is not true".

Comment: Why is `===` easier than `!==`?

Comment: `!==` and `===` mean generally opposite things, as your own code demonstrates. So it should be obvious why you cannot use them interchangeably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use conditional statements to convert the operators for most common cases. In your example, it would be easy and readable to convert the non-equal operator to equal operator by using if-else. But what if a condition like this?

```
if(i > 4 && i < 10 && i !== 8)
```

Do you want to apply converting logic here to replace the non-equal operator? The more you convert, then more complicated and unreadable your code is.